# Can I match the beginnings of words?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm  building a small filter utility for users to quickly filter a list of items and I want to match the beginnings of words in order, preferably using regular expressions:

Consider a user trying to find the item labeled `here is some text`.

- I already know how to make it match the beginning of any one word:

**her** — **her**e is some text — `\bher`
**so** — here is **so**me text — `\bso`
**ext** — *no match* — `\bext`

- And I know how to make it match first letter of several words:

**hist** — **h**ere **i**s **s**ome **t**ext — `\bh.*?\bi.*?\bs.*?\bt`
**ht** — **h**ere is some **t**ext — `\bh.*?\bt`

- What I need is the ability to match the first `n` characters of several words:

**herst** — **her**e is **s**ome **t**ext
**iso** — here **i**s **so**me text
**teh** — *no match*

I'm doing this because my items often contain intialisms, and a user may type **usc** to try and quickly pull up **US**A, **C**alifornia

I'm rewriting the pattern for each input, so I can do a little work then, as is necessary in case #2. I'm looking for a solution that will scale linearly with character count, in either pattern complexity or total complexity.

Given these constraints, what is my best option for matching these strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monstrosities like:

```
 \bh(.*?\b)?e(.*?\b)?r(.*?\b)?s(.*?\b)?t
```

Essentially, every letter is either preceded by the previous one, or a random sequence ending with a word boundary `(.*?\b)`. So, we make this random sequence + \b optional with `?`. So, breaking it up with `(.*?\b)?` between all the letters should work.

Comment: Monstrosity, yes, but it fulfills all my requirements perfectly. Hopefully performance will not be an issue..

Comment: Performance wise, if your regex implementation supports it, you could make the `(.*?\b)?` non-capturing with `(?:.*?\b)?`, which saves a little bit of resources. But I'm more worried about the amount of backtracks with longer strings.

Comment: I'm just searching relatively small items from the list (a few dozen characters) so hopefully backtracks won't be a huge issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is doable with the standard regexp libraries.

But given your constraints, you should be able to write your own parser to do the matching. Keep a stack of the pattern and then scan through the input text from start and forth. The only state you need to track is whether the previous character was a boundary or took an item off the stack. If you reach end of input without emptying the stack, it was a no-match.

In pseudo code:

```
pattern = "herst"
input = "here is some text"
state = true
until input.empty? or pattern.empty? do
  if input[0] == pattern[0] and state
    pattern.shift!
  else
    state = is_boundary(input[0])
  endif
  input.shift!
done
return pattern.empty?
```

Comment: I was thinking about writing my own parser, but could you go into a little more detail? I was under the impression I'd have to keep track of more than just the word boundary.

Comment: Totally off the top of my head example given. No warranties given there, but I think it would work like that.

Comment: (Preemptive details! Fantastic.) If Wrikken's monstrosity is too intensive I'll implement this.

Comment: hehe. must be the timezone difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult, if not impossible, to do this in a flexible manner with pure regexps. One possible approach that occurs to me is to first attempt a simple regexp match using word boundaries as you've already done, and then to generate a set of all possible prefix and suffix pairs and match against those. If, however, you want to be able to match against arbitrarily more than two separate words within a string, you should probably write a simple function that walks through the string being searched, attempting to match against the longest prefix from the query string. Once you find that longest prefix, you move on to the next word in the search string, and attempt to match against the remainder of the query (that is, minus the already matched prefix), and continue to do this until either the entire query has been matched, or the searched string ends. This should be fairly easy to implement recursively.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `^<myregex>` for the beginning of the string and `<myregex>$`for the end.

Comment: ...which is *not* what the question is about.